# I'm getting an error that a class has no members which has been defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I've been learning Python for one week now and I've been trying to create a text based game. Everything so far is good, I've been able to write lots of useful code but I just get this same problem and I don't know why.

Whenever it's time to define the name and the color of the character (its a frog). I thought that using a class would be the most appropiate thing, the problem is that when I try to call the member to change its content I get the next problem: Class Frog has no 'name' member, it also happens with color

The problem is that I defined it in the class which contains the player atributes.

Here is the piece of code that is giving me problems.

```
class Frog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = str
        self.color = str

def changeAtributes():
    print("change name")
    option = input("--> ")
    Frog.name == option
    print("\nchange color")
    option = input("-->")
    Frog.color == option

changeAtributes()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code fails on indentation errors.

Comment: You seem to be confused about how to write an instance method vs a main-program function.  I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do -- your main program call is to a normal function, but the function itself seems to think it should change class attributes.  I suspect that you need another pass through your introduction to classes, just to clarify someof your usage and terminology.

Comment: You say that you're trying to change something about a Frag "character", but you haven't made an instance of the class.  What is a "character" in your application?  You seem to have a nice idea of how short your code should be, but we need code specific to a *single* problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change attributes of the class itself, not instantiations of that class - i.e., you have to first define a frog with something like `frog = Frog(name='nick', color='green'` and then call your `changeAttributes` function like so:

```
def changeAtributes(frog):
    print("change name")
    option = input("--> ")
    frog.name = option
    print("\nchange color")
    option = input("-->")
    frog.color = option

frog = Frog(name='nick', color='green')
changeAtributes(frog)
```

Comment: Can you fix the assignments to the attributes? Ok, fixed. +1

Comment: yeah, noticed that afterwards :P

Comment: It would be better to show instance methods, using the traditional name 'self'

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiate your class. You have to first assign the parameters of `name` and `color` in the dunder `__init__` which is in the Frog Class. After *that* you will be able to modify the values in the `changeAttributes` function. And to change the values in the Frog Class using the function, you have to pass the instantiated class as an argument to teh function.

```py
class Frog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = str
        self.color = str

def changeAtributes(frogObject): # Pass frogObject as an argument.
    print("change name")
    option = input("--> ")
    Frog.name == option
    print("\nchange color")
    option = input("-->")
    Frog.color == option

frogObject = Frog("Molly", "Green")
changeAtributes(frogObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeAtributes` function should be a method of the class `Frog`, not a regular function.

A method is like a normal function, but it's first argument is `self`.

```py
class Frog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def changeAtributes(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        """return a string representing the class instance"""
        return f'name: {self.name}, color: {self.color}'


frog = Frog("jumpy", "red")
print(frog)
print("change name")
name = input("--> ")
print("\nchange color")
color = input("-->")
frog.changeAtributes(name, color)
print(frog)
```

```
$ python frog.py 
name: jumpy, color: red
change name
--> sleepy

change color
-->blue
name: sleepy, color: blue
```